# Automatically Update Record in Salesforce using DML

Tags: data-loader, update, force-cli

I need to automatically update a record in Salesforce and I'm wondering how can I transform my existing [Process Bean](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line) to update a certain record in Salesforce.

```
<bean id="ExportOpportunityProducts"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
      singleton="false">
  <description>csvExportOpportunityProducts extracts Opportunity Line Items from salesforce and saves into CSV file."</description>
    <property name="name" value="csvExportOpportunityProducts"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://login.salesforce.com"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value=""/>
    <entry key="sfdc.password" value=""/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="OpportunityLineItem"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
    <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select OpportunityID, PricebookEntryID, Quantity, CreatedDate, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem "/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value=""/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key `<entry>` tag you need to modify is that with `key="process.operation"`. You need to use `value="update"` instead. Take a look at **[Data Loader Command-Line Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_operations.htm)**, which lists out the available values for `process.operation`. Also useful is **[Data Loader Process Configuration Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_params.htm)**. I would imagine you need to also change the `dataAccess.type` to `csvRead`. You may need to tweak additional parameters, but these two references should give you a guide.